# Updating a template with a component input

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-meteor

Preface: I'm new to Meteor, Angular, and Typescript, so there is a very real possibility of an XY problem somewhere in here.

I'm working on a simple project management app using Meteor and Angular 2 (using the [angular2-meteor](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor) package) where the structure (for now) consists of projects which have events. One view is a list of projects. Clicking on a project shows a modal of the project's details, including a list of the project's events. So, three components: `ProjectList`, `ProjectDetails`, and `ProjectEventsList`. `ProjectDetails` uses a `Session` variable to know which project to show, and that works. However, the list of events in the modal doesn't update after it is created for the first project clicked on.

**ProjectEventsList.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {MeteorComponent} from 'angular2-meteor';

import {ProjectEvents} from 'collections/ProjectEvents';


@Component({
    selector: 'projectEventsList',
    inputs: ['projectId']
})

@View({
    templateUrl: '/client/projectEventsList/projectEventsList.html'
})

export class ProjectEventsList extends MeteorComponent {
    projectEvents: Mongo.Cursor<ProjectEvent>;

    projectId: string;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.subscribe('projectEvents', this.projectId, () => {
            this.autorun(() => {
                this.projectEvents = ProjectEvents.find({projectId: this.projectId});
            }, true);
        });
    }
}
```

As I understand it (though I may be way off here), I'm having difficulty getting `autorun` to, well, automatically run. I've tried putting a getter and setter on `projectId` and it does get updated when I click on a project, but the code inside `autorun` doesn't run after the first click. Things I've tried:

- Switching the nesting of `subscribe()` and `autorun()`.
- Adding/removing the autobind argument to both `subscribe()` and `autorun()`. I don't really understand what that's supposed to be doing.
- Moving the subscribe code to a setter on `projectId`:

  ```
  private _projectId: string = '';
  get projectId() {
      return this._projectId;
  }
  set projectId(id: string) {
      this._projectId = id;

      this.subscribe('projectEvents', this._projectId, () => {
          this.projectEvents = ProjectEvents.find({projectId: this._projectId});
      }, true);
  }
  ```

  When I do this the list stops displaying any items.

If this all seems like it should work, I'll create a small test case to post, but I am hoping that something in here will be obviously wrong to those who know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got the setter method working, as shown below. It feels clunky, so I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to do this, but the below is working for me now (i.e., the list of events is updated when the parent component (ProjectList) sends a new `projectId` to the input.

**ProjectEventsList.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {MeteorComponent} from 'angular2-meteor';

import {ProjectEvents} from 'collections/ProjectEvents';


@Component({
    selector: 'projectEventsList',
    inputs: ['projectId']
})

@View({
    templateUrl: '/client/projectEventsList/projectEventsList.html'
})

export class ProjectEventsList extends MeteorComponent {
    projectEvents: Mongo.Cursor<ProjectEvent>;

    set projectId(id: string) {
    this._projectId = id;

    this.projectEventsSub = this.subscribe('projectEvents', this._projectId, () => {
        this.projectEvents = ProjectEvents.find({projectId: this._projectId}, {sort: { startDate: 1 }});
    }, true);
}

get projectId() {
    return this._projectId;
}

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.subscribe('projectEvents', this.projectId, () => {
            this.projectEvents = ProjectEvents.find({projectId: this.projectId});
        }, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.subscribe()` and `this.autorun()` doesn't seem to be part of the Angular component class. If this is an external library you might need to explicitly run it in an Angular zone for change detection to work:

```dart
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  this.subscribe('projectEvents', this.projectId, () => {
        this.autorun(() => {
            zone.run(() => {
              this.projectEvents = ProjectEvents.find({projectId: this.projectId});
            });
        }, true);
    });
 }
```

If you want to subscribe to events fired from the component itself use host-binding

```dart
@Component(
  {selector: 'some-selector',
  host: {'projectEvents': 'projectsEventHandler($event)'}
export class SomeComponent {
  projectsEventHandler(event) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first half about zones: This was not a concept I was familiar with, so thanks for alerting me to that distinction (i.e. running code outside of the Angular zone)! Cool. However, I don't think it solves the root problem - that autorun never auto runs.

Comment: Yeah, it took a while until I started to understand your question. What about the 2nd part?  Where does that event come from?

Comment: `ProjectEventsList` is inserted with this code in `ProjectDetails`:

`<projectEventsList [projectId]="project._id"></projectEventsList>`

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by event, but when I click a project in `ProjectList`, it updates `ProjectDetails` and sends the new input value to `ProjectEventsList`. But then `ProjectEventsList` doesn't do anything with that updated id.

Comment: I still have a hard time what behavior you expect. Can you please add more code that demonstrates how `PeojectEventList` and `ProjectList` are related. A plnkr would be great.